# android opengl es: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, exception, opengl-es

I'm developing game and i want to show Dialog when player fail or complete level. Code like this.

```
    @Override
   public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
       if(fail) {           
    Dialog restart = new Dialog(SquareRenderer.this);
    restart.setContentView(R.layout.restart);
    restart.show();

        }
    }
```

log cat says Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

How can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a `Handler`? This will allow you to show the `Dialog` on the UI thread. Create your `Handler` like so...

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 0:
            Dialog restart = new Dialog(SquareRenderer.this);
            restart.setContentView(R.layout.restart);
            restart.show();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

... And then when you you need to display it just send the message to your `Handler`...

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if(fail) {           
        handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it now. it throws "java.lang.illegalstateexception system services not available to activities before oncreate()"

Comment: Where did you put the handler? By the sounds of it you need to put it in after your Activity has obtained its context. Did you try instantiating the `Handler` at the end of you're `onCreate()` or if it is in your rendering class (which I assume it is) then instantiate it in your constructor.

Comment: my class is like that public class Renderer extends Activity implements Renderer i put handler in onCreate it throws NullPointerException now

Comment: Did you make sure to define the `Handler` outside of the `onCreate()` and instantiate it inside of the `onCreate()` Also if you are going to use this inside of another class you will need to pass it to that class. I really can't help too much more unless you post some of your code above.